# AngularJS: ng-model not getting applied on Controller instantiation

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a web app planner using Angular and I am having some difficulties with a `<select>` box that is not changing value based on the variable denoted with `ng-model`.

My architecture is as follows:

I am using `ui-router` which gives me different view states, one for each page of my planner.  The root HTML page has a Controller called `MainController`. This is where I set up my JSON model, `$scope.Master = {}` that I want to use throughout the planner. All pages of the planner should inherit this model and continue to modify/add to it.

I then have my 4 pages of the planner like:

`Start -> Accounts -> Settings -> Review`

Each page has its own Controller that gets instantiated every time I visit the page.  On the `Start` page, I have a `<select>` box that has `ng-model="$scope.Master.Start.selectedAccount"` that gets populated dynamically using the `StartController` (therefore it gets populated every time I come to the Start page).

This `<select>` works great on the first time to the page, but if I go to `Accounts` and then come back, the select box is back to the default value, "Please select an account", instead of the selected account that is in the `$scope.Master.Start.selectedAccount` model that is bound to the `<select>` box

I thought I could just do something like `$scope.$apply` or something in order to re-apply the binding to the DOM object, but that just gave me an error saying it is already digesting.

How can I apply the binding to the `<select>` box after the page has been loaded 2 or more times?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because every time you go back to your original page, a new controller is instantiated since it was removed from the DOM when you left it originally. Thus `$scope.Master.Start.selectedAccount`. To save this, you can either

1. Use a service / factory singleton on the main app to save this value
   https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#!
2. Save `$scope.Master.Start.selectedAccount` as a global variable
   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope
3. Put that controller on the outside

Comment: `$scope.Master.Start.selectedAccount` is not the problem.. I have it in a parent controller so that value is persisting just fine! the problem is the `<select>` is not initializing its value to that of `$scope.Master.Start.selectedAccount`.. understand?

Comment: When I come back to the page for the second time, I can print `$scope.Master.Start.selectedAccount` to the screen and it contains the value I want. The problem is the DOM does not reflect this

Comment: Yeah... not sure about it, ng-model should bind when it is put on the DOM. Are you sure it is printing out correctly?

Comment: Yes.. I have `{{ Master | json }}` at the bottom of my page and it is not the default value "-1", it is the value it should be... I wonder if this is a bug in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Im real sorry... I realized I was populating the `<select`> using `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options` no idea how I managed that... That was the problem